# Trying to play audio in C# (Using Xamarin Studio)

Tags: c#, audio, soundplayer

After trying to run a simple audio player, I get this error:

`System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Here's my code:

```
using System;
namespace PurePlayer
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("~/Desktop/audio.wav");
        player.Load();
        player.Play();
    }
}
}
```

Please help me figure out why the audio will not play.

FYI, I am running OSX

Comment: If you give the fully qualified path like below, is it playing?

E.g.

System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:/FolderName/audio.wav");

Comment: you need a file URI: `"file:///~/Desktop/audio.wav"`